# BASH Get input from STDIN while using | (pipe)

Tags: bash, curl, checksum

I'm creating a new script. I would like to implement a way to verify this script. So I'm using those commands to check the content of the file.

```bash
remote_file="$(curl -m2 -s "$1")"
checksum_remote="$(echo "$remote_file" | sha256sum | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
checksum_current="$(sha256sum < "$COMMAND_NAME" | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
```

But after further developments I realize that I could use my script with the command `curl -s $SCRIPT_URL | bash`. In this case my check `[ "$checksum_remote" != "$checksum_current" ]` always succeed as the `$COMMAND_NAME` is `bash` and not the content of my script.

Is anyone know how to retrieve the whole source code with the bash script itself when we are using pipe execution?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `cat $(which "$COMMAND_NAME")` or something else?

Comment: It depends if you have the checksum of the source code or the binary^^

Comment: I guess I could use something like `tail -n +3` to save the checksum of my source code into the 2 lines of my source code.